# How to fix "The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed."

Tags: java, sql-server, tcp, sqlconnection

The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".

This is for java netbeans 8.2 version and running sql server 17.I’ve tried on existing servers and always seem to end up having to TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed.
following codes::::

```
private void signin1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        user= username.getText().trim();
        pass= password.getText().trim();

        try{ 

    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");  
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=xyz;integratedSecurity=true");  

     Statement statement = connection.createStatement();  

 ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(" select id, password from signin where username='"+user+"' and password='"+pass+"' ");  


  if(resultSet.next()){

           new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
                this.setVisible(false);
            }

         } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {  
             e.printStackTrace();  
         }  
    }
```

Comment: Does your server have the TCP/IP connection enabled? (I seem to recall it was disabled by default in some versions) And is it actually running on localhost?

Comment: It's enable and running

Comment: Try "netstat -ano" (if windows) and check which process is listening on port 1433 by checking PID in task manager.